# Distance between a point and an open set in euclidean space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

This is one of my Analysis quizzes.

Let $S$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the following holds:
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash S^\circ\; \forall y \in S \backslash \{x\} \quad d(x,S) \neq ||x-y||$$
The problem was to prove or disprove the converse. I tried to prove it, assuming there is some $x\in bd(S) \cap S$. But I cannot find some $z\in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash S^\circ$ which satisfies $d(z,S) = ||x-z||$.

Am I doing right? Or is it false?

Comment: What is $S^\circ$? If it’s the interior of $S$, then it’s simply $S$, since $S$ is open.

Comment: Yes, it is the interior of S. However the problem ask me to show that S is open.

Comment: With "the converse" you mean that if the proposition holds then the set must be open?

Comment: Yes, sorry for confusing you.

Comment: If that's so, then the converse is false: consider $S=\{ \frac{1}{n} : n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ and the point $x=0$.

Comment: The proposition says 'for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash S^\circ$'. If $x$ is not $0$, there is some $y$ satisfying $d(x,S) = ||x-y||$ with your set $S$.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to  give a counter example to disprove the reverse order of the above implication.

Let $n=1$, $S= \mathrm{Q} $ the set of rational numbers. $S$ is not open since $S^°= \phi \neq S$.  On the other hand,  we have  $ \forall x \in R $ ($x$ is not in $S^° = \phi$), and  $\forall y \in  \mathrm{Q} $ such that $y \neq x$, we have, $d(x,y)\neq 0$, however, $d(x, S)=d(s,\mathrm{Q} )=0$ ( Since  the closure of $S= \mathrm{Q}$ is $\mathrm{R} $).